# Plot a histogram, but don't know why the relative frequency shows greater than 1

Tags: r

I was trying to find the relative frequency of vector a, but the y-axis is showing numbers greater than 1. The relative frequency should be less than or equal to 1, right? Below is my code.

```
a = vector()
for (i in 1:100){
          flips <- rbinom(4,3,0.5)
          X <- mean(flips)
          a <- append(a, X)
    }
mean(a)
sd(a)
hist(a,freq=FALSE,main="100 Binomial Random Variables", xlab="Number of Successes",ylab="Relative Frequency", col="lightblue")
```

Comment: If you find my answers useful, please mark them as "solved". Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

Maybe this (follow the directions of OP and no need of unknown packages):

```
#Data
a = vector()
for (i in 1:100){
  flips <- rbinom(4,3,0.5)
  X <- mean(flips)
  a <- append(a, X)
}
#Plot
hist(a,freq=FALSE,
     main="100 Binomial Random Variables",
     xlab="Number of Successes",
     ylab="Relative Frequency", col="lightblue",right=FALSE)
```

Answer (score 0):

Here is an option with `ggplot`

```
library(ggplot2)
library(tibble)
tibble(a) %>% 
       ggplot() + 
          geom_histogram(aes(x = a), bins = 30)
```

#### data

```
a <- c(2, 2.5, 1.25, 1.25, 1.5, 1.75, 1.75, 2.25, 1.5, 2, 1.75, 1.75, 
1.5, 1.5, 1, 2, 0.5, 1.75, 2, 1.5, 1.75, 1, 1.5, 1, 1.75, 1.75, 
1.75, 1.5, 1.75, 1.5, 1.25, 1.5, 1.25, 1, 1.5, 1.5, 2, 1.25, 
1.25, 1, 1, 1, 2.5, 1, 1.75, 1.75, 1, 2.25, 1.75, 0.75, 1.5, 
1, 2.25, 1.5, 2.25, 2, 1, 1, 1.25, 1, 1, 1.75, 2, 1, 1.5, 2.5, 
1.5, 0.75, 2, 2, 1.25, 1.75, 1.75, 1.25, 1, 1.25, 1.75, 2, 1.75, 
0.5, 1.25, 1, 1.75, 1.5, 1.75, 1.75, 1, 1, 1.25, 1.5, 1.75, 1.25, 
1, 1.5, 2, 2.25, 1.25, 1.25, 1.5, 1.5)
```

Answer (score 0):

Histograms come in 2 forms: **frequency or density histogram**. Both of them are not what OP requests. Hint about it is provided when there is no custom y axis label: the axis receives either *Frequency* or *Density* label, based on the choice in `freq` option.
Essentially, what OP is looking for is to plot tabulated (frequency) vector:

```
table(a)
```

which can be achieved with a base R barplot:

```
barplot(height = table(a) / length(a))
```

Please note:

1. OP receives **frequency** barplot if `height = table(a)`,
2. OP receives **relative frequency** barplot if `height = table(a)/length(a)`, that's frequency is divided by the total number of observations.

The reason for y axis values being above 1 in density histogram is because it is the chart area that must be equal to total probability of 1. **On a density histogram, y axis doesn't show probabilities**.